# Codility extreme large Number error

Tags: testing

I have a Codility test to take soon. 
I was trying to find a modification in the code to avoid EXTREME LARGE NUMBERS ERROR by using LONG instead of INT... but this did not work.

Has anybody tried using CODILITY demo test and get a 100?

I went through previous posts but no solution to this particular problem.

MY CODE: COMPLEXITY O(N)... Still I got 94.

```
   // you can also use includes for example:
// #include <algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<math.h>

int equi ( const vector<int> &A ) {
if((int)A.size()==0)
    return -1;

long int sum_l = A[0];
long int total_sum =0;

for(int i =0; i<(int)A.size();i++){
    total_sum = total_sum + A[i];
    }

    int flag =0;
    total_sum = total_sum -A[0];

    if(total_sum == 0)
        return 0;

for(int i=1; i<(int)A.size()-1;i++){
    total_sum = total_sum - A[i];
    if(sum_l ==total_sum){
        flag=1;
        return i;
        }
    sum_l= sum_l + A[i];
    }
if(sum_l ==0)
    return (int)A.size()-1;

if(flag ==0)
    return -1;


}
```

Comment: Opps I just tried long long for sum_l and total_sum! and that error was resolved!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 2):

I used `long long`, and I had not problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
    int left = A[0];
    int right = 0;

    for(int i: A){
        right += i;
    }
    right -= left;

    int diff = Math.abs(left - right);
    for (int i = 1; i < A.length-1; i++) {
        left += A[i];
        right -= A[i];
        int a = Math.abs(left - right);
        if(diff > a){
            diff = a;
        }
    }
    return diff;
```